# Are there any way to insert multiple input (same or different cells) in Google Spreadsheets / script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

This is my current code, which only allow one input on cell C2, I am wondering if I can just add another input, either in cell C2 or in other cell. Thank you very much for your guidance, newbie here!

```
function onEdit()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="T-D-SOC")//It will only do this on Sheet1
  {
  var lr=sh.getLastRow();
  var name=sh.getRange('C2').getValue();
  sh.hideRows(2, lr-1);
  var allRanges=ss.getNamedRanges();
  var rows=[];
  for(var i=0;i<allRanges.length;i++)
  {
    if(allRanges[i].getName()==name)
    {
      var rgi=allRanges[i].getRange();
      var toprow=rgi.getRow();
      var numrows=rgi.getNumRows();
      sh.showRows(toprow, numrows);
      sh.showRows(2,19);
      break;
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write in a cell, just define the range of another cell and write in it with `setValue`:

```
sh.getRange('C3').setValue('My text');
```

Comment: I may own programs I often use the same text box to allow multiple inputs using forwards slashes as delimiters and then use String.split('/') in order to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a value you in a specific range, you will have to use the `setValue` method **or** if you have multiple values, you can also make use of the `setValues` method.

However, depending on what exactly you want to achieve, you may want to check the event object `e` since you are using an `onEdit` trigger.

For instance, if you want to retrieve the range in which the edit was made, you can simply use this:

```
let editRange = e.range.setValue("VALUE").
```

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Range Class - setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue);
- [Apps Script Range Class - setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues);
- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).